# Detect Languages; CakePHP updateAll Bad Performance

Tags: php, sockets, localhost, cakephp-3.0, language-detection

***UPDATE: I think the cakePhp updateAll is the problem. If i uncomment the updateAll and pr the results i get in 1-2 seconds so many language Detections like in 5 minutes!!!! I only must update one row and can determine that row with author and title... is there a better and faster way???***

I'm using [detectlanguage.com](https://detectlanguage.com/) in order to detect all english texts in my sql database. My Database consists of about 500.000 rows. I tried many things to detect the lang of all my texts faster. Now it will take many days... :/

- i only send 20% of the text (look at my code)
- i tried to copy my function and run the function many times. the copied code shows the function for all texts with a title starting with A

I only can run 6 functions at the same time... (localhost)... i tried a 7th function in a new tab, but

> Waiting for available socket....

```
     public function detectLanguageA()
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

    $mydatas = $this->datas;

    $alldatas = $mydatas->find('all')->where(['SUBSTRING(datas.title,1,1) =' => 'A'])->where(['datas.lang =' => '']);

    foreach ($alldatas as $row) {
    $text = $row->text;
    $textLength = round(strlen($text)*0.2);
    $text = substr($text,0,$ltextLength);
        $title = $row->title;
    $author = $row->author;
            $languageCode = DetectLanguage::simpleDetect($text);

    $mydatas->updateAll(
                ['lang' => $languageCode], // fields
                ['author' => $author,'textTitle' => $title]); // conditions*/

    }
}
```

I hope some one has a idea for my problem... Now the language detection for all my texts will take more than one week :/ :/

My computer runs over 20 hours with only little interruptions... But i only detected the language of about 13.000 texts... And in my database are 500.000 texts...

- Now i tried sending texts by batch, but its also to slow... I always send 20 texts in one Array and i think thats the maximum...

*Is it possible that the cakePhp 3.X updateAll-function makes it so slowly?*

Comment: What plan are you using? Are you hitting the API limits?

Comment: Current plan - Plus
1M requests/day
200 MB/day
I dont hitting the limits...

Comment: Have you tried to send texts by batch? It should be faster: https://github.com/detectlanguage/detectlanguage-php#batch-detection

Comment: okay i try this... how many texts should i try???

Comment: I don't know the API, but 100 may be a reasonable number.

Comment: rather than sending 20% of who-knows-how-many characters, it might make more sense to send a specific number of characters. Maybe detectlanguages could give you a guideline for character-count. For instance, they may claim that their algorithm is 95% accurate on 30-character strings.

Comment: since you are processing such a large amount of data, it probably makes more sense to process it locally on your machine, rather than sending it to a remote machine and waiting for a response each time. for example, [here](https://github.com/feedbackmine/language_detector) is ruby gem for language detection

Comment: I would go for CLD2 language detector which is very efficient. You dont need to feed it with all text, just a chunk, like 100 words would be enough. https://github.com/fntlnz/cld2-php-ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM WAS THE CAKEPHP updateAll**

Now i'm using: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data with a for loop and all is fast and good

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

 $articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');

    for ($i = 1; $i < 460000; $i++) {
        $oneArticle = $articlesTable->get($i);

        $languageCode = DetectLanguage::simpleDetect($oneArticle->lyrics);

        $oneArticle->lang = $languageCode;
        $articlesTable->save($oneSong);
    }
```